# How do I store a huge amount of data inside Sqflite database inside my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use Sqflite inside my flutter app to Implement Dictionary functionality. and I have more Than 4 Table that store a single's word definitions in to different Languages.

I have almost 3000 words in which each word have 3 word's definitions in different languages. how I store all these words inside sqflite database. and also I want to display three(3) words when the user searches a single word. because each word have three definitions in different languages

1. how do I create and connect all my table so that when the user searches a single word three word words are displayed.(each word in different languages)
2. How do I implement a search bar functionality so that the user can search words from sqflite database, the user searches one word and get Three words in different language's

I created two tables, one to store a single word with their id, an the other table is to store three word's which is the definition of the first word in three different languages, I use a foreign key to reference the the ID of the word in the first table. I use these id to store 3 words which is the definition of a single words in the first table, so how i Insert those data in both tables please help me??

Here is how I created the two tables:

```
 class SqlfdatabaseHelper{
      Future<Database> initializeDB() async {
        String path = await getDatabasesPath();
        return openDatabase(
          join(path, 'example.db'),
          onCreate: (database, version) async {

            await database.execute(
              "CREATE TABLE WordsTable("
                  "WordId_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                  "Column_word TEXT NOT NULL,"
                  "Column_Languages Text NOT NULL,"
                  "knfdjgnkjfdkjdfhbkfdnbfgknhiofgjhrt)",
            );

            await database.execute(
              "CREATE TABLE WordsTable("
                  "WordId_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES WordsTable(WordId_id),"
                  "Column_word TEXT NOT NULL,"
                  "Column_Languages Text NOT NULL,"
                  ")",
            );
          },
          version: 1,
        );
      }
    }

my row Data is for examle.
                          ** Name (the first word in english) 
                                -abel (in spanish) 
                                - Dawit(in italy)
                                 -beby(in china)
```

AS YOU can see above each words have Three word definition inside. I want to store the first word in these case Name in the first table, and the remaing three word in the second Tables, and if the user is Search using the first word in these case Name. the three name

```
                             -abel (in spanish) 
                             - Dawit(in italy)
                             -beby(in china)
```

must be Displayed from the second Tables

Comment: Hi, So it is like a dictionary right ?, So if there are more number of words, it is better to store them in  a server in the cloud and access them realtime, Else you can by default store the values to a sqlLite DB on the device, and perform search operation using the TextEditingController or the TextFormField.

Comment: i want to implement an offline dictionary that is why i choose sqllite.

Comment: no need for a 4 tables: just use one table with one additional field: `languageId`

Comment: please can you show me how i implement  that? I can't figure it out, or if you have a link that teaches me that kind of Staff please help me?

Comment: all you need is `wordId`, `languageId` and `text` fields, so for example you have one record in english: (211, 0, "sun") and the second in spanish (211, 1, "sol") and another one in french: (211, 2, "soleil") - here languageId == 0 means english, 1 means spanish and 2 means french language, now when you want to find all "sun"s use `"select * from foo where wordId = 211"

Comment: OK, so where to start? how I create those table and how I connect them?  do yo have some links that redirect me to learn that kind of staff

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/index.htm and/or https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: I created one table, is it possible to see i in Diagram. how to generate Design view. or i want to see my table  where is it created inside my flutter app

Comment: As you Said i created the Two Tables.  can you help me a little on how to add the data in to the two tables. Please see my code above.

Comment: my row Data is for examle.     ** Name (the first word in english)                                                          
                                                             -abel (in spanish)                                                                      
                                                             - Dawit(in italy)                                                                           
                                                              -beby(in china)

Comment: AS YOU can see above each words have Three word definition inside. I want to store the first word in these case Name in the first table, and the Remaing three word   in the second Tables,